# Not Able to Access Swagger UI with spring mvc, Getting 404

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

I have Configured swagger with my application(Spring MVC), I can see the documentation in JSON format if I am accessing https://IP:port/app/v2/api-docs.

But if am trying to access https://IP:port/app/swagger-ui.html, I am getting 404. Please find my configurations below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>    

<bean id="swagger2Config" class="springfox.documentation.swagger2.configuration.Swagger2DocumentationConfiguration">
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="swagger-ui.html" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"/> 

<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you try https://IP:port/app/swagger-ui/index.html

Comment: Yes, I have tried swagger-ui.html, swagger-ui/, swagger-ui.index.html. but no luck :(